# Use Websocket Client in graphql resolver for data communication Nodejs

Tags: node.js, websocket, graphql

i want to connect to a websocket server, when my graphql server starts, and inside a resolver i want to use send and recv functions of the connected websocket for data communication.

brief about my backend,
i have a python rest client that also have a websocket server, i can fetch solo product details and product list via the websocket server.

(in graphql resolver i want to collect my products data and also an inventory data and merge them both for UI. ***as node is async programming, and all the example are connect to server then, use a then block and communicate, i dont want to do that i want to use the connection object in resolver and the connection should be done once.***)

```
import { WebSocketClient } from './base';

const productWebSocket = new WebSocketClient("ws://192.168.0.109:8000/abi-connection");
productWebSocket.connect({reconnect: true});

export { productWebSocket };
```

now i will import this productWebSocket and want to use it in resolvers.

this websocket and graphql shi* isnt that popular, but designing this shi* this way gives me a performance boost, as i use utility functions for both of my restapis and websocket server in core-apis. i call this maksuDII+ way of programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i couldnt do this with nodejs and got no help. so i implemented graphql with python and got more better control in websocket client.

***i search for ws, websocket some other shitty packages in nodejs none worked***

```
websocket.on('connect', ws=> {
 websocket.on('message', data => {
  // this shit is a  argument how am i suppose to get this value in a express api end point.
  // search total 5 pages in google got nothing so have to shift to python.
 })
})
```

python Version

```
from graphql import GraphQLError
from ..service_base import query
from app.websocket.product_websocket import product_ws_connection
from app.websocket.inventory_websocket import inventory_ws_connection
import json
from app.utils.super_threads import SuperThreads


def get_websocket_data(socket_connection, socket_send_data):
    socket_connection.send(json.dumps(socket_send_data))
    raw_data = socket_connection.recv()
    jsonified_data = json.loads(raw_data)
    return jsonified_data


@query.field("productDetails")
def product_details(*_, baseCode: str):
    
    product_ws = product_ws_connection.get_connection() # connected client, with proper connection to my websocket server
    inventory_ws = inventory_ws_connection.get_connection()

    if not product_ws:
        raise GraphQLError("Product Api Down")
    if not inventory_ws:
        raise GraphQLError("Inventory Api Down")

    product_ws_data = {
        "operation": "PRODUCT_FETCH",
        "baseCode": baseCode
    }

    inventory_ws_data = {
        "operation": "STOCK_FETCH",
        "baseCode": baseCode
    }


    # super threads here is a diffrent topic, it a wrapper around standard python Threads.
    ws_product_thread = SuperThreads(target=get_websocket_data, args=(product_ws, product_ws_data))
    ws_inventory_thread = SuperThreads(target=get_websocket_data, args=(inventory_ws, inventory_ws_data))

    ws_product_thread.start() # asking one of my websocket server for data.
    ws_inventory_thread.start() # same with this thread.


    product_data_payload = ws_product_thread.join() # i get the what websocket gives me as response
    inventory_data_payload = ws_inventory_thread.join() # needed this type of shit in nodejs could not have it.

    if "Fetched" in product_data_payload["abi_response_info"]["message"] and \
        "Fetched" in inventory_data_payload["abi_response_info"]["message"]:
        
        # data filtering here

        return product_data
    else:
        raise GraphQLError("Invalid Product Code")
```